# Defining an external tool for my IDE plug-in via Eclipse launching API

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext, launching-application

I tried to create, as user from my Xtext plug-in, a new external tool configuration to simply execute a .bat wich launches an external compiler of the language for which I'm implementing an IDE using Xtext. I did so by selecting External Tools -> External Tools Configurations... -> New Program, and then by filling the information about location of the .bat, working directory and arguments. This was very simple.

Now, I'm trying to define directly in my plug-in this external tool which executes my .bat, by using the Eclipse launching API, but I found very difficult to understand how I could obtain this... I don't understand if there is some class which implements ILaunchConfigurationDelegate that I can extend to automatically launch my .bat (or in general, to launch a program!).

Have you any hint, or is there some simple example about implementing an external tool that simply launches a .bat (or program in general), using Eclipse launching API?

Thanks in advance,
Marco